# With pmd rulesets in maven, how do you select an individual rule?

Tags: java, maven, pmd

I'm using the following to look at bad exception patterns in [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) [in maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/):

```
<configuration>
    <rulesets>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml</ruleset>
    </rulesets>
</configuration>
```

This is what I want to do, but it doesn't work (for diagnostics and focusing on particular needs)

```
<configuration>
    <rulesets>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidCatchingThrowable</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/SignatureDeclareThrowsException</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/ExceptionAsFlowControl</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidCatchingNPE</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidThrowingRawExceptionTypes</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidThrowingNullPointerException</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidRethrowingException</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/DoNotExtendJavaLangError</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/DoNotThrowExceptionInFinally</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidThrowingNewInstanceOfSameException</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidCatchingGenericException</ruleset>
        <ruleset>/rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidLosingExceptionInformation</ruleset> -->
    </rulesets>
</configuration>
```

My question is: **With pmd rulesets in maven, how do you select an individual rule?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not directly possible with maven.

I'd recommend creating a custom ruleset file and reference this single ruleset in pom.xml instead.

Custom Ruleset File: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.2.3/customizing/howtomakearuleset.html

Example (filename `custom-ruleset.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Custom ruleset"
    xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
  <description>
    Only some selected rules for bad exception patterns
  </description>

  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidCatchingThrowable" />
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/SignatureDeclareThrowsException" />
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/ExceptionAsFlowControl" />
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidCatchingNPE" />
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidThrowingRawExceptionTypes" />
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidThrowingNullPointerException" />
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidRethrowingException" />
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/DoNotExtendJavaLangError" />
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/DoNotThrowExceptionInFinally" />
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidThrowingNewInstanceOfSameException" />
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidCatchingGenericException" />
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidLosingExceptionInformation" />

</ruleset>
```

Please note, that you need to specify the original ruleset name without a leading slash, otherwise PMD won't find the ruleset. 
There are also a couple of other tricks possible with a custom ruleset, e.g. importing a complete ruleset but [exclude one or more rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.2.3/customizing/howtomakearuleset.html#Excluding_rules_from_a_ruleset).

Maven PMD Configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <rulesets>
        <ruleset>custom-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
    </rulesets>
</configuration>
```